# Electron JS: Change positioning of an Element (eg. Button, Label ...)

Tags: javascript, html, electron

how can i change the positioning of a button in a window?
I want to create new inputboxes right, next to the existing input boxes, but when i create one, it always sets the new box under the last created. Is there anyway to give an x- and y coordinate for a button, input, label?
Cant find anything in the docs, i am also new to JavaScript and Electron.

[image: edit button positioning]

Here is my code:

main.js:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1000,
        height: 1000,
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');

    mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
        mainWindow = null;
    });
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow();

    app.on('activate', () => {
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
            createWindow();
        }
    });
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

ipcMain.on('userInput', (event, userInput) => {
    // Handle the user input here
    console.log('User input:', userInput);
    // You can perform actions with the user input as needed
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Input Desktop App</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
       <h1>Nutritions</h1>
       <label for="userInput">Carbohydrate:</label>
       <input type="text" id="userInput">
       <button id="submit">Submit</button>
       <label for="userInput">Protein:</label>
       <input type="text" id="userInput">
       <button id="submit">Submit</button>
       <label for="userInput">Fat:</label>
       <input type="text" id="userInput">
       <button id="submit">Submit</button>
   </div>
   <script src="renderer.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.container {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 30px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

label, input {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

button {
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    padding: 7px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Thx in Advance

Comment: I guess you should put the label, input and the button inside a parent div so you can have more control over each element position

Comment: you can force your inputs to `display: inline;` via CSS (currently, they're set to `display: block;`)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Electron, it's a CSS question really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn about Flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Change your .html file to something like this:

```
    <div class="container">
       <h1>Nutritions</h1>
       <div class="input-container">
        <div>
         <label for="userInput">Carbohydrate:</label>
         <input type="text" id="userInput">
        </div>
        <div>
         <button id="submit">Submit</button>
         <label for="userInput">Protein:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
         <input type="text" id="userInput">
         <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div>
         <label for="userInput">Fat:</label>
         <input type="text" id="userInput">
        </div>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
```

Then in your .css file you can do this:

```
 .input-container {
  display: flex;
 }
```